# Emacs color theme that looks like Xcode dark

Tags: xcode, emacs, aquamacs

I really like the Xcode dusk color theme, and I was trying to get something similar for my Aquamacs/Emacs. I can't seem to find any out there. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4):

You might like the [zenburn](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorThemeZenburn) colour theme, which I think is similarly calming :)

[image: screenshot of emacs with the zenburn colour theme]

Comment: +1. You can also get rid of the tool bar with `M-x customize-variable tool-bar-mode`.

Comment: `Alt + PrintScreen` creates  [a single window screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HLCfI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've created [xcode light/dark theme](https://github.com/juniorxxue/xcode-theme) for Emacs, enjoy!

[image]